# How to make prompt appear every time untill the wanted value is entered

Tags: javascript

This is a simple JS example that works and I'm trying to "improve" it a little.
I'm a JS total beginner and I hope I'm not stepping in over my head here.

```
var color1 = prompt("Enter first color: yellow, red or blue");
var color2 = prompt("Enter second color: yellow, red or blue"); 

if (color1 == "yellow" && color2 == "yellow"){
      console.log("mixing of these two colors makes yellow");
    }
if (color1 == "red" && color2 == "red"){
      console.log("mixing of these two colors makes red");
    }
if (color1 == "blue" && color2 == "blue"){
      console.log("mixing of these two colors makes blue");
    }
if (color1 == "yellow" && color2 == "red" || color1 == "red" && color2 == "yellow"){
      console.log("mixing of these two colors makes orange");
    }
if (color1 == "yellow" && color2 == "blue" || color1 == "blue" && color2 == "yellow"){
      console.log("mixing of these two colors makes green");
    }
if (color1 == "blue" && color2 == "red" || color1 == "red" && color2 == "blue"){
      console.log("mixing of these two colors makes purple");
    }
```

What I want to do is not to allow the second prompt to appear until the first prompt is properly (accurately) entered (which is:yellow, red, blue), no matter how many times the user enters the "wrong" value. 
I know that I have to use "while" but I'm not sure how. Tried a couple of times with different approaches, but didn't managed to get desired result.
Also tried some threads with similar problems but couldn't find solution for this specific problem. 
Any help or suggestions are more than welcome.
Thank you.

Comment: Use while loop to check the value of color1 against the fixed values stored say in an array

Comment: You should show an example where you tired `while` loops, because then it would be possible to tell you what your missunderstanding in your approach is.

Comment: Without running into something too complex, here is a little snippet that may help you: https://jsfiddle.net/8spbqfwn/2/ . Here we are looping (while) until both color1 and color2 are setted and exists in a previous declared list (array), so that if you either mispell or just don't tell a color it will prompt the color prompt over and over again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use while loop like shown below

```
var colors = ["red","yellow","blue"];
var color1 = prompt("Enter first color: yellow, red or blue");
while(colors.indexOf(color1)==-1){
    color1 = prompt("Enter first color: yellow, red or blue");
}
var color2 = prompt("Enter second color: yellow, red or blue");
```

Comment: You can further optimize the code: `var color1;
while(!['red','yellow','blue'].indexOf(color1)) {
    color1 = prompt("Enter first color: yellow, red or blue");
}
var color2 = prompt("Enter second color: yellow, red or blue");`

Comment: thank you Aditya K, this is exactly what I was looking for. <br/>
btw repeated prompt does not work on jsbin but on codepen works just fine :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var valid_colors = ['yellow', 'red', 'blue'];
var color1;
var color2;

color1 = prompt("Enter first color: yellow, red or blue");

while (!~valid_colors.indexOf(color1)) {
    color1 = prompt("Enter first color: yellow, red or blue");
}

color2 = prompt("Enter second color: yellow, red or blue"); 

while (!~valid_colors.indexOf(color2)) {
    color2 = prompt("Enter second color: yellow, red or blue");
}

//... continue with your code
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
var allowedColors = ['yellow', 'red', 'blue']; //we create array of valid input

var color1 = ''; // initial value is not correct, so user is prompted at least once.

var color2 = '';

while(allowedColors.indexOf(color1) === -1){

    color1 = prompt("Enter first color: yellow, red or blue");

}

while(allowedColors.indexOf(color2) === -1){

    color2 = prompt("Enter second color: yellow, red or blue"); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use a while loop, also could make function as its used more times

```
function getUserInput(n) {
  let color;
  while (!(color=="red" || color=="yellow" || color=="blue")) {
    color=prompt("Enter "+n+". color (red, yellow or blue):");
  }
  return color;
}

var c1=getUserInput(1),
    c2=getUserInput(2);
```